# Windows Horizontal Black lines in Dual Boot| T480

Tags: linux, windows-10, drivers, display, multi-boot

I have been having a very peculiar problem with my dual boot Windows 10.

[Screen Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwLhY.jpg)

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAjkF.jpg

But first specs...

#### Hardware

- Thinkpad T480
- i7-8550U
- RAM 8GB
- Intel UHD Graphics 620
- GeForce MX150
- TOSHIBA-RC100 (Windows is installed here, this drive is installed in WWAN slot)
- WDC PC SN720 SDAQNTW-256G-1001(Linux is installed here. The drive is the preinstalled Lenovo drive)

#### Software

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Windows 10

The black lines appear for no apparent reason while using Windows. It happens under full load, very small load, straight after boot or after very long use. I have been unable to find any reasonable pattern of its behavior.

At first, I thought that it was the display itself which was damaged. As I have recently sent it off to repair to fix the frame which was coming off. But when using Linux I don't get the same problem. From this, I concluded that it cannot be the display hardware issue.

My second guess was that one of the display drivers was corrupted and needed to be replaced. Therefore I have uninstalled and reinstalled Intel and Nvidia drivers. This was also in vain. Although now I started getting additional behaviors where the screen would sometimes freeze now without blacklines for about 5 seconds or up to 5 min. The screen would remain static whereas the system would still be working on the background (for example I would still be able to stop and start youtube).

By the way, this might be important but I have switched off Nvidia GPU in Linux, therefore I only use Intel on Linux. Windows uses both Nvidia and Intel.

As my final option, I have completely reinstalled Windows (keeping Linux). For a few days, everything was smooth. Until yesterday, when those damn black lines came back.

I feel defeated, I don't see any other reason for this issue.

Linux is my main OS, so I bearly use Windows, but I still need it as I am using it for photo editing (Photoshop, Lightroom).

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?